# Google Cloud SQL - Lost connection and Timeout errors

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I keep getting the following errors when attempting a simple connection to a Google Cloud SQL database instance from a PHP script.

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0(2013)

and

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in .../users_log_in_db_connect.php on line 18
```

I'm aware the following errors may have already been covered but having attempted most suggestions as per related posts below I'm still unsuccessful in solving them:

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654311/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste)

LINK 2

For example when I set my server to localhost or 127.0.0.1 I get the following error:

```
 DB connection failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)(2002)
```

For the log in details I'm using my server value is the Instance IP address provided in the Google Developers Console.

I'm being driven crazy by these errors and I know I'm missing out on a really simple thing. Where could I be going wrong?

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? You will need to add the IP address where you connect from to the whitelist for you Cloud SQL instance, and you'll also need to connect to the IP address of your CLoud SQL instance, not localhost/127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the IP you are connecting from isn't authorized in the console, as stated in the docs:

> If Google Cloud SQL rejects the connection, for example, because the
>   IP address your client is connecting from is not authorized, the error
>   you receive will be: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL
>   server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

See the "configuring access control for IP connections" section on the following [page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appaccess):